# How many judges sat on Galileo's trial and who were they exactly?

Tags: history

I saw several chronologies of the trial online but most of them only mention the name of Urban 8 as involved in the actual court proceedings. How many judges were involved and who were they exactly? Some useful information can be found [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18107/how-many-judges-sat-on-galileos-trial-over-heliocentrism-and-who-were-they-exac).